# terraform not initializing variables from the module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am very new to terraform. I am trying to deploy aws dynamodb table using it.

I have created following files:

1. variables.tf
2. dynamodb.tf  -> contains dynamodb table resource
3. output.tf
4. provider.tf
5. main.tf -> contains module with initializations of required variables.

when terraform is running its giving error like:

```
Error: Invalid value for variable
on variables.tf line 154:
variable "application-owner" {

This was checked by the validation rule at variables.tf:
```

I have confirmed that variable names case is same at both places.

what might be the issue with this.

Comment: It's saying the **value** is invalid. It is picking up the value, but the value you provided is invalid.

Comment: i have cross verified value and the value in module is valid email id. it is picking "" as default value and trying to verify whether it is email id or not.

can(regex("^[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@xyz.com$", var.application-owner))

Comment: please show your code